# Is it OK to italicise only part of a word?

Tags: typography, italics

As an example: *in*homogeneous.

Comment: Yes, of course. When you want to emphasize a single syllable of a word, it's fine. I'd show you, but the SE UI doesn't allow it.

Comment: Markdown doesn't allow it, but you don't have to use that.

Comment: @Robusto   . 

Comment: @Robusto this time, probably the first time in ELU story,  you are wrong! SE UI does allow the tag 'em' cojoined with other letters. Please, see my edit version. Haha.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I think Robusto meant in his comment.

Comment: As in man’s *in* humanity to man?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine.  For example.

> Jack thinks it is impossibly difficult, but I think it only im***plaus***ibly so.

Comment: I edited your answer to show the font style (with 'em' and 'strong' tags.) 'b' and 'i' tags do not function in cases like this.

Comment: @Carlo_R. 'b' and 'i' are perfectly fine and, indeed, still included in the HTML5 spec. If your UA can't cope with valid tags, that's another matter entirely.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not saying that 'b' and 'i' are not valid tags, but only that SE UI does not allow them in conjunction with other letters, as it is demonstrated by the fact that your edited version of the question does not show 'in' in italic fonts. At this pourpose you should write <em>in</em>homogeneous, not <i>in</i>homgeneous as you have done.

Comment: Because it worked for me. The syllable *in* **was** in italics.